# PayPal Developer Account for Software Product

Tags: paypal

I am working on a software product that will support credit card processing via PayPal.  The issue I am running into when setting up the PayPal Developer Account, is it appears to be structured to be set up only by the person processing payments.  How should I set this account up?  Do I set it up as if I were processing the payments directly and then just swap out the credentials for each user?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to make calls on behalf of 3rd party account holders?  If that's right then yes, you could have them enter their own API credentials into your app settings and then swap them out accordingly, or you could use the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/gs_PermissionsService/).